# ProcessPoolExecutor: member variable lost in returned objects

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, future, python-multiprocessing

I've a class like this based on `defaultdict`, which also has a member variable that is a defaultdict (my guess: this is where the problem lies?):

```
from collections import defaultdict
class A(defaultdict):
  def __init__(self):
    super(A, self).__init__(int)
    self.B = defaultdict(int)

  def methodA(self, id):
    # update values in self.B and self[key], for example:
    # self[id] = 1000
    # self[1] = 1
    # self.B[id] = 2000
    # self.B[2] = 2

  def get_B(self):
    return self.B.iteritems()
  def get_dict(self):
    return self.iteritems()
```

I'm using `concurrent.futures` to create different instances of `A` like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

futures = []
num_processes = 2 #some integer value

def process_parallel(id):
  A_1 = A()
  A_1.methodA(id)
  return A_1

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as exec:
  for p in range(num_processes):
    futures.append(exec.submit(process_parallel, p))

for f in as_completed(futures):
  A_instance = f.result()
  # iterate over A_instance.get_dict() and A_instance.get_B
  # A_instance[1] can be accessed, but A_instance.B is empty
```

The problem is after the futures have completed and returned their results, the `B` member variable contains nothing. To check, I make sure that `B` is non-empty and can even print its elements at the end of the `methodA`, but once back in the main process, suddenly `B` seems to be gone.

Should `B` be initialized separately? What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening here is that the ProcessPoolExecutor is using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to serialize and deserialize your class instances, and the contents of the  defaultdict that is the 'B' attribute of your instances are not preserved.

You can verify this by creating and updating instances of your class in the interpreter, pickling and unpickling them and examining the results.

If you create a container class to hold both defaultdicts they both survive pickling and with their contents intact, so this is probably the best approach.  For example (assuming python3):

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = defaultdict(int)
        self.bar = defaultdict(int)

    def baz(self, value):
        # update defaultdicts
```